# How to let Tor change IP in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, tor

I have found this script https://gist.github.com/estliberitas/4448496 about changing Tor identity, but I don't really understand so much about cookiePath and cookie in this script.

I am using Ubuntu-installed Tor. How to get cookiePath in my machine? Or is there any way to change Tor identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure TOR control is enabled in the configuration with the `CookieAuthentication` authentication method

**torrc file**

```
## The port on which Tor will listen for local connections from Tor
## controller applications, as documented in control-spec.txt.
ControlPort 9051
## If you enable the controlport, be sure to enable one of these
## authentication methods, to prevent attackers from accessing it.
#HashedControlPassword 16:872860B76453A77D60CA2BB8C1A7042072093276A3D701AD684053EC4C
CookieAuthentication 1
```

Then you can run "estliberitas" script with the path to your cookie in argument:

`nodejs tor-identity.js /home/ubuntu/.tor/control_auth_cookie`

Note: You can get the cookiePath by using `locate control_auth_cookie`